# How to attach a signature to a file?

Tags: javascript, c#, signature

I know how to sign any byte array, but I don't understand still how to attach my signature to target file? For example, I have some JSON-file:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@gmail.com"
}
```

Will it right solution?

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
    "signature": "here-is-my-signature"
}
```

But exist many file types (XML with schema, dll, etc) and this method not always is suit.

Is there a common way to sign files? How is the signature stored in it? Maybe for this there is a separate file property, like "when created", "file size", ... "signature"?

Comment: I'd argue that verifying the signature of a JSON file if you've modified the JSON could potentially be troublesome. Beyond that I have no idea. Is there a specific signing scheme you're working to?

Comment: Signature has meaning if someone forcefully checking it. For people it is "license" which they agree or disagree, for machines it is digital signature. Simple way is just calculate it yourself and place in some kind of storage. Usually signature storage, where md5/sha256 of file is key, and value is signature. And deny any execution if storage is not provided or invalid.

Comment: @John for this case it is possible to verify each time a copy JSON-file with  replaced `signature` value by `null`.

Comment: @John Yes, I want to check binary content with excluding  ​​from verification value of signature field. But this is just my guess of solving a particular case. Is there any general approach for signing files?

Comment: My worry with JSON is that if the serialized order of properties changes, if the JSON is saved without indentation sometimes, and saved with indentation other times (or the indentation changes in some way) then a signature for basically the same object won't be valid. If it has to be that exact object, presented exactly like that, then I guess it's OK.